# SQL select in list A but create row even when not in list A

Tags: sql, oracle

I've tried searching for solutions, but couldn't find any. Please point to right direction if duplicate.

[Problem]
I want to query for a list of userIDs(`('hunter1', 'hunter2', 'hunter3')`) and check if they have agreed to our privacy policy.
However, here's the catch - **even when the userID isn't in our database, I need a row with that userID with "N" to policy agreement status**.

[AS-IS : Current query]

Query explanation: there can be multiple entries for a single userID because that user could've joined & left & joined again. **Simply put, this query returns userID and its status where that userID has the highest sequence number if that userID can be found multiple times.**

```
SELECT
    userID,
    policyAgreementStatus
FROM
    MEMBERTABLE m
WHERE
    userNoSeq IN (
        SELECT
            MAX(userNoSeq)
        FROM
            MEMBERTABLE
        WHERE
            m.userID = MEMBERTABLE.userID AND MEMBERTABLE.userID IN 
                 ('hunter1', 'hunter2', ...)
    )
ORDER BY userNoSeq;
```

The above query will return something like below if 'hunter1' is nonexistant in the table.

```
userID      policyAgreementStatus
-----------------------------------
hunter2             Y
hunter3             N
...
```

[TO-BE]

I want a result where it returns:

```
userID      policyAgreementStatus
-----------------------------------
hunter1             N
hunter2             Y
hunter3             N
```

even when hunter1 was not in the table in the first place.

The easiest way I can think of is to make a temporary table or use a PL/SQL collection and join it with the original table.
**However, I am working on a Read-Only database so that's impossible.**
Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create objects to use a collection, there are some built-in ones. For instance you could supply your list of IDs as an [`ODCIVarchar2LIst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/addci/extensibility-constants-types-and-mappings.html#GUID-0C7F23BA-A9CA-472E-8830-FDF4BFA5556F), expand that into individual elements, and then left-join to you real table:

```
WITH userIDs (userID) AS (
    SELECT
        column_value
    FROM
        TABLE(SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('hunter1', 'hunter2', 'hunter3'))
)
SELECT
    u.userID,
    COALESCE (
        MAX(m.policyAgreementStatus) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY m.userNoSeq),
        'N'
    ) AS policyAgreementStatus
FROM
    userIDs u
LEFT JOIN
    MEMBERTABLE m
ON
    m.userID = u.userID
GROUP BY
    u.userID
ORDER BY userID;
```

The `coalesce()` supplies the default N value when there is no match, as the left-join would leave that null. I've switched from your sub-select [to use `max ... keep dense_rank last`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LAST.html#GUID-4E16BC0E-D3B8-4BA4-8F97-3A08891A85CC) as it's a bit shorted, but your original query would still work too.

You may already have your own collection types available, and exactly how you implement depends on where the list of values is coming from and how it is (or can be) supplied to the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LEFT` outer join and `MAX` analytic function. A CTE holds all the userids.

```
with h(userID) as
(
  select 'hunter1' from dual union all 
  select 'hunter2' from dual union all 
  select 'hunter3' from dual 
)
SELECT userID,
    COALESCE(policyAgreementStatus,'N') AS policyAgreementStatus
FROM
( SELECT
    h.userID,
    m.userNoSeq,
    m.policyAgreementStatus,
    COALESCE (
        MAX(m.userNoSeq) OVER (partition by h.userID ),
        0
    ) AS max_userNoSeq
FROM
    h 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    MEMBERTABLE m
ON m.userID = h.userID
    ) WHERE max_userNoSeq IN ( userNoSeq,0) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as:

```
select m.userid,
       coalesce(max(mt.policyAgreementStatus) keep (dense_rank first order by userNoSeq desc),
                'N'
               ) as policyAgreementStatus
from (select 'hunter1' as userid from dual union all 
      select 'hunter2' from dual union all 
      select 'hunter3' from dual 
     ) m left join
     membertable mt
     on mt.userid = m.userid
group by m.userid;
```

You can get the most recent `policyAgreementStatus` using the `keep` syntax.  I have found that this is quite efficient in Oracle.